# Header in the first section of UITableView shows with a jump

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I've got a strange bug with header in static grouped table view. It shows only once transition animation ends (apparently on didMoveToParentViewController). UISplitViewController is the root view controller. Example project can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fwi5266hdstld5/JumpingTableView.zip?dl=1). Actually this is a very simple project from Master-Detail Application template. Any suggestions for resolving this bug will be appreciated.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Show the code in your `viewDidAppear` class of the master view controller (with the jumpy header).

Comment: There is no any code in viewDidAppear. Even more, there is no even a class for MasterViewController. It's a default view controller from Master-Detail Application template. The only edits I've made: 1) changed tableview content from dynamic prototypes to static cells; 2) changed tableview style from plain to grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's Simple Just remove Under Top Bar from both Master Scene To Remove
>
> -> Go to Storyboard File
>
> -> Select Master Scene
>
> -> Click on Attributes Inspector(4th Tab)
>
> -> Under Extended Edges, Unclick Under Top Bar.
> [image: Please Find Screenshot to understant more]